# Null after @InjectMocks in Mockito Junit

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am having some troubles passing a dependancy while unit testing with JUnit.

Consider these pieces of code:

This is the dependacy injecton into the class which i want to test, lets call it Service.

### error log trace

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.demo.service.ServiceClass.getCustomerById(ServiceClass.java:50)
    at com.example.demo.service.ServiceClassTest.getCustomerByIdTest(ServiceClassTest.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
```

### ServiceClass

```
@Service
public class ServiceClass {

    public static final String CRM_JPA_URI = "http://localhost:9000/api/tickets/";

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;


public Customer getCustomerById(int customerId) {
    ResponseEntity<Customer> entity = restTemplate.getForEntity(CRM_JPA_URI +"ticket/{customerId}",
            Customer.class, customerId);
    return entity.getBody();
}
```

}

### ServiceClassTest

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ServiceClassTest {

    @Mock
   RestTemplate mockRestTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    ServiceClass serviceClass;


    /**
     * getCustomerByIdTest
     */
    @Test
    public void getCustomerByIdTest(){

        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setPassengerName("Ramesh");
        customer.setBookingDate("09/09/2019");
        customer.setDestStation("pamur");
        customer.setEmail("r@gmail.com");
        customer.setSourceStation("ongole");

        Mockito.lenient().when(mockRestTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:9000/api/tickets/ticket/1", Customer.class)).
        thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<Customer>(customer,HttpStatus.OK));

        System.out.println("object is--->"+serviceClass.getCustomerById(1));

        assertEquals(customer, serviceClass.getCustomerById(1));

    }

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am getting null pointer exception when I call service class in my test class

Comment: And the stack trace of the exception is?

Comment: @JB Nizet i edited my question with stack trace

Comment: OK. Now read it. The exception is thrown at line 23 of ServiceClass. My guess is that this line is `return entity.getBody();`. Do you confirm? If you do, what could possibly null at this line and thus cause a NullPointerException?

Comment: Its returns object I checked that

Comment: Ttat comment doesn't ranser my questions, and doesn't really help. The stack trace indicates that the error is called from the method `ServiceClass.getAllTickets`. there is no such method in the code you posted. And we also have no idea of wht line 23 is. Please post the **real** code of the test, and the **real** code of the ServiceClass. And tell which line is line 23 (assuming the stack trace is the real stack trace).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198837/discussion-between-krish-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: i added log trace correctly now but i am not understating why null pointer exception is coming.entity.getBody() return object i checked it

Comment: You need to reason logically. The exception can only be thrown because `entity`is null. So why is it null? Because `restTemplate.getForEntity(...)` returns null? Why does it return null? Because you haven't told the mock rest template what to return when this method is called with these arguments. Look at the URL in the code. look at the URL in the test. They're not the same.

Comment: There is also much better methods of testing rest templates within a Spring Boot application that can deal with customizations to the message converters etc. to enable more effective testing.

Comment: @Darren Forsythe can please guide me with better way with your code?

Comment: JB Nizet entity.getbody returns null from test class but its return object when i call from controller class

Comment: Why this is happening? any diff among that calls?

Comment: Do you understand what a mock is? A mock is a fake instance of a class. It doesn't do anything of what the actual mocked class does. It only does what you tell it to do. You've told your mock to return a value when its method is called with the URL "http://localhost:8080/getCusomerById/1", For all other URLs, it will return null. And your code calls it with a different URL. So it returns null.

Comment: i tried with same your but still returning null object as i edited my code above,its working fine and return object when i call it from my RestController class,But returning null when i call method from my test class

Comment: When you call it from your RestController, you use a **real** RestTemplate, which really sends an HTTP request. When you use it from your test, a **mock** restTemplate is used, which doesn't do anything other than what you tell it to do. You haven't told it to do anything when it's being called with the 3 arguments `CRM_JPA_URI +"ticket/{customerId}"`, `Customer.class` and `customerId`. So it returns null. The only thing you've told your mock to do is to return something when it's called with 2 arguments `"http://localhost:9000/api/tickets/ticket/1"` and `Customer.class`.

Comment: How can I write test case for this can you please paste some code

Comment: If you want to keep using mocks, all you need to do is to mock the correct method, with the correct arguments, i.e. the method that your ServlceClass actually calls, with the arguments that your service class actually uses. Do you understand what I'm telling you? If not, what is unclear? Pasting some code that you can copy and paste won't make you understand. And if you don't understand, you'll make the same mistake in 2 hours.

Comment: i am clear about what your saying and i am asking that how can we implement test case for above ServiceClass method

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mock-rest-template i followed this tutorial exactly\

Comment: If you're clear about what I'm saying, have you at least tried to do what I'm advising to do? What did you try to do? Post what you tried.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-rest-client

Answer (score 0):

Try calling

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

in your test method or @Before setup() method

Comment: Doesn't apply here. `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` does do that for you automatically. Thus: when you lack the deep knowledge of the subject, consider to comment, instead of giving a **wrong** answer.